# Is there any file format for SIP calls?

Tags: file, sip

Is there any generic [sip](/questions/tagged/sip) call file format like `.sip`, `.sipcall` or `application/sip.call` that would contain everything from a SIP session including [dtmf](/questions/tagged/dtmf), timestamp & receiver?

I've seen diverse ways of saving SIP calls to disk but none that looks standardized.

[asterisk](/questions/tagged/asterisk) has something called ["Call Files"](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+Files).

The file format would be for archiving calls that have happened in the past, i.e. not for scripting calls.

Comment: Are you looking for a format which shows the destination for a call so you can e.g. double-click to dial? Or for a format which records call history data for a call which took place?

Comment: @Ben for historical calls, like a recording but with tons of meta data. One could be able to "play" it in some kind of soft phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly .pcap/.pcapng is used, allowing to use Wireshark for filtering, graphing SIP message flow and even listening of some calls if RTP was also saved and particular codec is supported.

Answer (score 1):

RFC7865 describes a format for the call metadata required by a call recording server. The media type is `application/rs-metadata+xml`.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7865